# Meteor populate a collection on server start up

Tags: meteor

This code needs to `insert` some documents in MenuItems collection at server start up. But the browser console shows it is an empty [].
I have no idea what this _.each mean, just got it off another post.

Why and how to fix it please? Thanks

```
///////////////////////////
//     both/both.js      //
///////////////////////////
MenuItems = new Mongo.Collection('menuItems');

///////////////////////////
//    server/server.js   //
///////////////////////////
Meteor.publish('menuItems', function(){
  return MenuItems.find();
});
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var items =
    [
      {menuItem: "task1", login: false},
      {menuItem: "task2", login: true},
      {menuItem: "task3", login: true},
      {menuItem: "task4", login: true},
      {menuItem: "task5", login: true},
      {menuItem: "task6", login: true},
      {menuItem: "task7", login: false},
      {menuItem: "task8", login: false},
      {menuItem: "task9", login: false},
      {menuItem: "login", login: false},
      {menuItem: "logout", login: false}
    ]
  _.each(items, function (doc) {
    MenuItems.insert(doc);
  })
});

///////////////////////////
//   client/client.js    //
///////////////////////////
Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: function () {
    return MenuItems.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the menuItems publication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you removed `autopublish` package, in your client/client.js file, you need to subscribe to `menuItems` publication.

```
///////////////////////////
//   client/client.js    //
///////////////////////////
Template.mainMenu.onCreated(function () {
    var template = this;
    template.handler = template.subscribe('menuItems');
});

Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: function () {
    return MenuItems.find();
  }
});

Template.mainMenu.onDestroyed(function () {
    var template = this;
    if (template.handler && template.handler.stop) template.handler.stop();
});
```

P.S: [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) iterates over the array and call the function the function per each item in the element with the item passed as parameter to the function.